# how can split data into ranges

Tags: matlab, split, double, range

I have a list of numerical values C that represent hours and minuts: first column hours, second column minuts

```
C=[19 44;15 57;15 19;0 21;20 21;20 20;0 6;22 0;21 17;17 47;23 51;22 27;21 39;21 36]
```

I want to split them in ranges:

```
ranges= {[0 0; 3 59] [4 0; 7 59] [8 0; 11 59] [12 0; 15 59] [16 0; 19 59] [20 0; 23 59]}
```

can you help me?

Comment: Please provide data in correct syntax.

Comment: I have modified the data, how they are and I have introduced the ranges

Comment: i would recommend you to go the transformation C=duration(C(:,1),C(:,2),0); in the beginning  and use the durations datatype, as you can do things like add and substract without having to deal with the 2 values issue you could face right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way would be to use "hist()" and "histcounts()"

as mentioned by user4694 those arent doubles but either durations or timestamps.
either way you have to transform them into doubles first i.e. with minutes() in the case of timestamps, and create the specific bins the same way. This is coded for duration

```
X=[duration(0,0,0) duration(4,0,0) duration(3,15,0)]; %and so on
bins=[duration(0,0,0) duration(4,0,0) duration(8,0,0)]
% if you just want the histogramm
hist(X,bins);
% if you want to know which element in X goes to which bin try
[amount_in_bin,Bins,which_bin]=histcounts(minutes(X),minutes(bins));
%or just go for the last one
[~,~,which_bin]=histcounts(minutes(X),minutes(bins));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to achieve this. Try the following code:

```
times = randi(20,1,30)+rand(1,30);   %% Example data. 

s = arrayfun(@(n) times(times>=0+4*n & times<(4*(n+1)-1)), 0:(24/4-1),'UniformOutput', False)'
celldisp(s)
s{1} =
    1.2963    2.4468    2.7948    1.5328    1.3507
s{2} =
    5.4868    5.6443    4.9390
s{3} =
    9.5470   10.6868   10.1835    8.7802    8.7757    9.4359    8.3786   10.5870
s{4} =
   12.8176   13.8759   13.6225
s{5} =
   16.9294   17.8116
s{6} =
   20.5108
```

If you want your values sorted:

```
s = arrayfun(@(n) sort(times(times>=0+4*n & times<(4*(n+1)-1))), 0:(24/4-1),'UniformOutput', False)'

celldisp(s)
s{1} =
    1.2963    1.3507    1.5328    2.4468    2.7948
s{2} =
    4.9390    5.4868    5.6443
s{3} =
    8.3786    8.7757    8.7802    9.4359    9.5470   10.1835   10.5870   10.6868
s{4} =
   12.8176   13.6225   13.8759
s{5} =
   16.9294   17.8116
s{6} =
   20.5108
```

Comment: I try with my data but it don't give me the result I want, I obtain this   s{1} =     []
  
s{2} =     5     6     5     6     5     6     5     6
  
s{3} =     9    10     9    10     9    10     9    10
 
s{4} =    13    14    13    14    13    14    13    14    13    14    13    14

s{5} =    17    18    17    18    17    18    17    18
 
s{6} =     21    22    21    22    21    22    21    22

Comment: I have numerical values that represent hours and minuts: a matrix in which a columns represents hours and an other minuts. I want to put this temporal time in the right interval...